# storing json element into javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

im using ajax retrieve database data with php and convert it to json

```
<?php
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

ajax function

```
ajaxCall("getdata.php", container, function (data) {
    var count = data.length
    var i;
    var array[];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        container.innerHTML += data[i].property; //this is doing well
        array[i] = data[i].property; //this when goes wrong;
    }
});
```

when I try to recal `array[i]` its return undefined , what do i do wrong?

Comment: Try `push`, `array.push(data[i].property);`

Comment: It's `var array = [];`, that's an error !

Answer (score 0):

Array initialization in JavaScript should be like **[`var array = [];`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)**

```
ajaxCall("getdata.php", container, function (data) {
    var count = data.length
    var i;
    var array = [];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        container.innerHTML += data[i].property; //this is doing well
        array[i] = data[i].property; //this when goes wrong;
    }
});
```

or you can use **[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** loop to iterate and **[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** for adding value to the array

```
ajaxCall("getdata.php", container, function (data) {
    var array = [];
    for (var v in data) {
        container.innerHTML += v.property; //this is doing well
        array.push(v.property); //this when goes wrong;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse.

Demo:

```
var json = '[{"result":"OK","count":1}, {"result":"NOK","count":2}]',
obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj[0].result);
alert(obj[1].result);

alert(obj[0].count);
alert(obj[1].count);
```

So in your case, it could look something like this:

```
ajaxCall("getdata.php", container, function (data) {
    array = JSON.parse(data);    
});
```